# can anyone tell about flow of service cloud

Tags: servicecloud

Can anybody tell me **flow of Service cloud** like sales cloud has like the following....

campaigns -->Leads -->{Accounts, contacts, Opportinuty}--> Deals won -->Orders

Comment: Flow you mentioned is of Sales cloud. From `Campaigns` -> `Orders`

Comment: @RahulSharma, can you please write flow of both Service cloud and sales cloud?

Comment: @RahulSharma can you tell flow for service cloud....?

Answer (score 0):

You can think of it by starting from the entry point via email-to-case/automated/manual entry/live chat. All of this results in Cases. Cases can have SLA's connected by using Entitlements, Milestones and Entitlement Processes alongside the standard objects like Account/Contact. A case should end a resolution (e.g. Closed) and can potentially result in a  knowledge article to support faster resolutions for future cases.